# Laravel 4.2 - pagination failing when using having distance as

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pagination, eloquent, query-builder

I have a complex search query built that works well until I introduce distance calculations..

This is how I do it..

```
        $profiles = Profile:: ... ... ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...

        $lat = Auth::User()->profile->latitude;
        $lng = Auth::User()->profile->longitude;
        $gr_circle_radius = 6371;

        /*
         *  Generate the select field for disctance
         */

        $disctance_select = sprintf(
            "*, ( %d * acos( cos( radians(%s) ) " .
                    " * cos( radians( latitude ) ) " .
                    " * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(%s) ) " .
                    " + sin( radians(%s) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) " .
                ") " .
            ") " .
            "AS distance",
            $gr_circle_radius,
            $lat,
            $lng,
            $lat
        );


        $profiles = $profiles->select( DB::raw($disctance_select) )
                             ->having( 'distance', '<', 80 )
                             ->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' )
                             ->paginate(12);
```

When I use paginate() I get this error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause'
```

If I use get() the query works but then I get

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()
```

.. and I would reallllyyy like o have easy pagination working.

Are there any good suggestions on how to address this. I have been searching around and found nothing useful.

Apparently there is an issue with eloquent when using having?

All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should move your `having` constraint to the `where` clause. Yes, I know the `distance` column doesn't exist. It doesn't matter, just move your logic there and it will work.

Comment: it doesn't work ... SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(51.503363) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.127625) ) + sin( radians(51.503363) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance from `profiles` where (`country_id` = 41 and .... and `distance` < 80 order by `distance` asc limit 12 offset 48)

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You need the logic in that `where`. This piece you have in your `select`. Mind that using `having` here is full table scan.

Comment: I know what you are saying.. but I can't do that.. I have to dismantle a function that constructs the query to inject that in and I can't do that currently. I will try to put more time into it still..

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is not solved then use `->simplePaginate(12)` instead of `>paginate(12)`

Comment: It would be nice to add the differences between `paginate()` and `simplePaginate()` and add an explation of why `simplePaginate()` works and `paginate()` doesn't. Thanks